# Nagios Custom Plug-in(https authentication) not working as expected

Tags: plugins, nagios

I am writing a plugin to check authentication to a https site and then search for a text in the response html,body to confirm successful login.  I have created the following plugin

```
#!/bin/bash
add_uri='--no-check-certificate https://'
end_uri='/'
result=$(wget -O- $add_uri$1$end_uri --post-data=$2)
flag=`echo $result|awk '{print match($0,"QC Domain")}'`;
echo $flag
echo "Nagios refreshes properly1"

if [[ $flag -gt 0 ]] ; then
echo 'ALL SEEMS FINE!!'
exit 0
   else
echo 'Some Problem'
exit 2
fi;
```

When I execute this plugin directly from command line

```
./check_nhttps <url here>  '<very long post data with credential information>'
```

The plugin works as expected(For both + & - test cases) and there seems to be no issues.
But when the plugin runs from Nagios,

```
check_command                   check_nhttps! <url here>  '<very long post data with    credential information>'
```

It always shows critical error(Prints else condition text "Some Problem" too). 
P.S : Tried sending the post data with double quotes also.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd think its very probable that your post data contains some characters that confuse nagios, maybe a space, or even a `!`. Better put the post data into some file and use --post-file. Also, you might insert `echo "$2" > /tmp/this_is_my_post_data_when_executed_by_nagios` into your script and check if the post data is ok.

Comment: Finally got it working  turned out the ordering of arguments in commands.cfg was wrong. Ur idea of printing the arguments in script was helpful!!! Thank you for the help!!! 